# AutocompleteSupportFragment window closing as soon as I type a letter in search bar android

Tags: types, window

I am using google place API in my app. and it is working fine in development mode, but when I publish a signed APK to play console and install an app from the play store, then the window of AutocompleteSupportFragment gets close as soon as I type a letter in the search bar.
has anyone faced this issue? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. the problem was that I had added the API key in only debug google_maps_api.xml file so when I published the signed APK to the play console then I got into this issue.
so make sure that you have completed these two points:-

1. first, you are using an unrestricted API key.
2. second, are you able to check if you've entered your API key within the google_maps_api.xml file in the release directory (/app/src/release/res/values) just like in your debug directory (/app/src/debug/res/values)?